# Mysterious std::list::size() mismatch

Tags: c++, list, c++11, iterator

I've got a "list iterator not dereferencable" error. I've figured that this is often caused by trying to iterate too far through a list, however I can't find the cause of it. I'm staying strictly within the functions of the `std::list` API, so I don't know what exactly is going wrong in the below code to cause this error.

There are a few mysteries surrounding the error. The main focus of this issue is `GameStateManager::HandleEvents()`, during the `list` iteration. At the point of breaking, I have added five elements to the list, called `list::remove()` for each (making an empty list) and added four more elements. However, as you can see below, I print the size of the list before iterating through it. While debugging, this has shown something confusing - the size, as returned by `list::size()`, is different from the actual size (as viewed in the list::size variable itself, via the Visual Studio debugger). This only happens prior to the error - normally both values are the same. However, right before the error, size() returns a value unequal to the size member value of the list. It consistently contains the previous value, prior to the first elements being removed. I can't help but feel this discrepancy has something to do with the "list iterator not dereferencable" error.

Additionally confusing, the print command is not executable immediately prior to the error-triggering code. Additionally, in `GameStateManager::HandleEvents()`, no custom breakpoints are triggered prior to fatal `for` loop. Perhaps these anomalies are separate issues, however I figured they may be useful to know.

GameStateManager.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Tools.h"
#include "TitleScreenState.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include "Timer.h"
#include <list>

class GameState;
class EventHandler;

class GameStateManager
{
public:
    GameStateManager(void);
    ~GameStateManager(void) { m_currentState->OnEnd(); }

    void Run(void);
    void Quit(void) { m_running = false; }

    // Event Handler Functions
    void AddHandler(EventHandler* handler) { m_eventHandlers.emplace_back(handler); }
    void RemoveHandler(EventHandler* handler) { m_eventHandlers.remove(handler); }

private:
    std::list<EventHandler*> m_eventHandlers; // All of the handlers who are passed the events
    bool m_running; // The universal boolean for whether or not the program is running
    int delta; // The time since the last frame
    Timer m_FPSTimer; // The timer that keeps track of the time since the last update
    GameStateID startStateID;

    GameState* m_currentState; // Pointer to the current game state

    // Poll and pass events to the current state
    void HandleEvents(void);
};
```

GameStateManager.cpp

```
#include "GameStateManager.h"
#include "EventHandler.h"
#include "ToolKit.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include <time.h>

GameStateManager* g_manager = nullptr;

GameStateManager::GameStateManager(void) 
    : m_eventHandlers(), delta(0), m_running(true), startStateID(GSID_TITLE), 
      m_currentState(nullptr), m_titleScreen(nullptr), m_game(nullptr)
{
    // Initialise time
    srand(time(nullptr));
}


void GameStateManager::Run(void)
{
    Initialise();

    while (m_running)
    {
        // State's key press responses
        m_currentState->OnKeys(SDL_GetKeyboardState(nullptr));
        // Update State
        m_currentState->OnUpdate(delta);
        // Render State
        m_currentState->OnRender();

        HandleEvents();
    }

    delete this;
}


void GameStateManager::HandleEvents(void)
{
    // Respond to events
    SDL_Event event;
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
            m_running = false; // Quit
        }
        else 
        {
            int size = m_eventHandlers.size();
            printf("Whooo! Size: %d\n", size);

            for (EventHandler* handler : m_eventHandlers)
                handler->OnEvent(event);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is some event handler de-registering itself in its OnEvent()? If so, this would break your iteration.

Comment: Can't tell for sure, but one problem I can envision is that any of the `handler->OnEvent(event);` calls invokes `GameStateManager::RemoveHandler` for some other handlers. Maybe the `for` loop would then fail to iterate the list correctly?

Comment: As a better-document-this-well work-around, make a copy of the `std::list<EventHandler*>` to a local automatic list or vector *before* the loop and enumerate *that* container instead of `m_eventHandlers`. If a handler revokes itself during the enumeration it will do so without effecting your enumeration. its just a list of pointers so replicating it should be quick.

Comment: Fair suggestions, but none of the handlers *should* dereference themselves. I'll try the local copy method and see how that goes, just to be sure. As it stands, the four handlers are menu items, such as Resume Game, exit game, etc. However are only executed if the event us a mouse click - the error is triggered without before any input could be given. Still, it's worth a try to check it out. Until then, any other suggestions would be appreciated. Perhaps following up the cause of the unexecuted print and breakpoint triggers prior to the for loop.

Comment: Just set a data breakpoint on size data member change and you'll see when exacly it changes unexpectedly. Either your list is being changed during iteration over it or it may be some memory corruption issue. As a side note: your code is not thread safe: at least m_running should be atomic.

Comment: @dlf I can confirm that no event handlers are de-registering themselves. Additionally, therefore, the local list workaround caused the same issue.

Comment: Another thought: is AddHandler called concurrently from more than one thread?

Comment: @dlf I know nearly nothing about multi-threading at the moment, so I can't say for sure, but I haven't purposefully added any multi-threading features. So assuming that single threading is the default, I would say no :P